# function declaration 'this' scope in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why the fetch image button `onClick` function works in function expression, but not function declaration in the same calling method.

```
class FetchButtom extends Component {

 async fectchImage() {
    const IMAGE_API = 'Some Image API';
    try {
      const images = await fetch(IMAGE_API);
      const json = await images.json();
      console.log(this);
      this.props.addImage(json.items);
    } catch (error) { }
  }

 fectchImageExpression = async () => {
    const IMAGE_API = 'Some Image API';
    try {
      const images = await fetch(IMAGE_API);
      const json = await images.json();
      console.log(this);
      this.props.addImage(json.items);
    } catch (error) { }
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          // console.log(this); -> this point to FetchButtom
          onClick={() => this.fectchImage()}
          // This will no trigger fectchImage runs
          onClick={() => this.fectchImage}
          // TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
          onClick={this.fectchImage}

          // Working perfectly, same as onClick={() => this.fectchImage()}
          onClick={() => this.fectchImageExpression()}
          // This will no trigger fectchImageExpression runs
          onClick={() => this.fectchImageExpression}
          // Working perfectly, same as onClick={() => this.fectchImage()}
          onClick={this.fectchImageExpression}
        >
          Fetch image
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, my question is why **function expression** have these 2 cases working `{() => this.fectchImageExpression()}` and `{this.fectchImageExpression}`, **function declaration** only working in `{() => this.fectchImage()}`

Comment: With `()` you are invoking the function

Answer (score 1):

- Why it works:
  Using the arrow function, an this is true also for property expression,
  you're actully binding **this** lexically (from surrounding declaration context).
- Why it don't work:
  Differently you'll inherit **this** from the scope where you call the function, and you'll be missing those methods.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` receives a function declaration - `() => this.fectchImage()` is an anonymous function which when invoked will run `this.fectchImage`. 
When assigning `this.fectchImageExpression` to `onClick` then you pass the function without running it, and when clicking it will run the passed `this.fectchImageExpression`.

When you assign `onClick` with `() => this.fectchImageExpression` It's an anonymous function that just has a reference for `this.fectchImageExpression`but without invoking it. So it's seems like it's doing nothing.